# Running VBA caps/replace script on multiple lines of pasted data

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, paste

I am running a VBA script to auto-capitalize and remove hyphens from pasted data into Excel.  This script works great on single-line pastes (single-cell), but will not run (does nothing to change the data) if multiple lines of data are pasted in.  The following is my code:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        With target
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("A:U")

        If Not Intersect(target, rng) Is Nothing Then
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                .Value = Replace(.Value, "-", "")
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With target
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Set rng = Range("A:U")

        If Not Intersect(target, rng) Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell in target
                If Not cell.HasFormula Then
                    cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
                    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "-", "")
                End If
            next cell
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @ElleryHiggins I just put in a new edit, please take a look; forgot to change the assignment side of the operator

Comment: Works perfect!!  Thank you so much!  This will save so much time!

Comment: Glad I could help. If it works for you please mark this as correct to close your question as answered!